# What does this regular expression: /[\[]/?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am struggling to understand what this means: `/[\[]/`  Why are there two replace statements?

```
name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
```

Answer (score 8):

`/[\[]/` is a [regular expression literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

In the first replacement, you're replacing a `[` by `\[` and the symetric in the second one.

It looks weird because of many (mostly useless) escapements : `[` is escaped in the regex and `\` and `[` are escaped in the string literal.

The first regex can be analyzed like this :

- `/` : regex opening
- `[` : character set opening
- `\[` : the `[` character (with an escaping that is useless as it's in a set)
- `]` : character set closing
- `/` : regex closing

Those regexes look too verbose to me : you don't need a character set if you have just one character in that set. And you don't need to escape the `[` in the string literal.

You could have done

```
 name = name.replace(/\[/, "\\[").replace(/\]/, "\\]");
```

For example

```
 'a [ b c ] d [ e ]'.replace(/\[/, "\\[").replace(/\]/, "\\]")
```

gives

```
 "a \[ b c \] d [ e ]"
```

Note that as there is no `g` modifier, you're only doing one replacement in each call to `replace`, which probably isn't the goal, so you might want

```
 name = name.replace(/\[/g, "\\[").replace(/\]/g, "\\]");
```

Comment: im sorry but i must be slow- i still dont understand. For example, if I understand it correctly, in /[\[]/  <-- [ is going to be replaced by \[   , but then what is the ending:  ]/  for ?

Comment: Just to add, I am pretty sure in PCRE you don't have to escape the square bracket, _i.e._ `/[[]/` would have worked fine. (This is definitely true of `/[]]/`, as wrong as it looks.) But yeah, `/\[/` would have been clearest.

Comment: @acheong87 I thought that too but as I already recommended to get rid of the set I didn't want to enter in this detail. What surprises me most is the escaping in the string literal. Not everybody know regexes  well but most coders don't escape all chars in string literals...

Comment: @acheong87 I found a place in my answer to mention the fact the [ escaping was useless too.

Answer (score 0):

That is using regular expression. If you are not familiar with regular expression, you may want to [study](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) that first.

Answer (score 0):

This really isn't specific to Javascript, regular expressions are used in most programming languages with slight variations. Look into regular expressions, very useful once you know it!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you will see how it works on example

```
var name = "[[[[[]]]]]]]";
name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
console.log(name);
```

as result you will have

```
\[[[[[\]]]]]]]
```

This regular expression replace first occurrence of `[` to `\[` and first occurrence `]` to `\]`